# PHP array when logged looks differently on server and locally

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, logging

I have a weird problem with PHP array.

Locally, when logged array looks like this:

```
array( 0 => '7')
```

Same array when logged on server looks like this:

```
array(7);
```

I am logging it using Monolog `\Log::info` method. PHP version on server is **5.5.20** and locally **5.6.6** I am using **Laravel** framework version 4.2

I was trying to enforce all kinds of casting, and adding keys but no luck.
This small difference is responsible for huge bug in my app.

Thanks

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on your array to see if they really are different, or if Monolog is just formatting it differently when logging. The second array you show still has a key of `0` (all arrays have keys), they appear to be the same array.

Comment: how are you viewing the array that makes it look like that? If that is code, then the arrays are exactly the same with the only exception being the first 7 is a string and the second is an int.

Comment: I am viewing it in laravel log file - both on server and locally
yes, they are the same. real problem is that value is cast to integer.

Comment: how are you casting the 7 to string? can you write what methods you tried?